# In Swift iOS, why are two identically sized nested UIImageViews different sizes?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I'm trying to sort out some AutoLayout issues dealing with UIImageViews. Can you identify why the following code:

```
    var image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"cat1.jpg")!
    var catView1 = UIImageView(image: image)
    catView1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    catView1.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.view.addSubview(catView1)

    var image2 : UIImage = UIImage(named:"cat1.jpg")!
    var catView2 = UIImageView(image: image2)
    catView2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    //catView2.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    catView1.addSubview(catView2)

    //Why are these two different views not the same size?
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Shouldn't these two images be the same size? I'm just not getting the Mask thing I guess.

Here's the project:
http://fm001-forumimages.s3.amazonaws.com/CenterConstraint3.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `translates... = false` allows the `UIImageView` to find it's natural size, which is going to be the size of the image, overriding the 100x100 size you've arbitrarily set.

Comment: OK that's a much better explanation than in the docs. Thank you very much! So if I'm going to use AutoLayout to position UIImageViews, I'm going to have handle resizing "manually"? Meaning AutoLayout is going to need the mask set to false, so I'm going to have to resize things myself?

Comment: Add a width and height constraint to the imageView to keep it a fixed size.

Comment: For that matter, to keep any view from finding it's natural size set height and/or width constraints.

Comment: Thanks David. Would I need to set height and width constraints on all nested (children) UIImageViews? Or do they propagate down? The docs say they propagate down, but it seems like they don't.

Comment: This is a fair way to think about the `translates...` property, but I wanted to mention that it does hide a little bit of complexity as to what that option *actually* does, as well as the function of `intrinsicContentSize`.